# How to create Neo4j node LABEL with bulk insert

Tags: neo4j

I am creating a text file to then Bulk insert into Neo4j.  This is working EXCEPT the nodes are not labeled.  The file I am loading has this text:

[{"method":"POST","to":"/node","body":{"ICD9":"79409","NodeType":"Dx","ID":2},"metadata":{"labels":["Dx"]}}]

What should it look like to create the label "Dx"?

I can use set after creating the nodes but this is slow and may time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs of the [Neo4j REST API](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api.html), there's no direct way to create a node with label(s). Since you're already using batches, it's fairly simple to add another call for [adding a label](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-node-labels.html#rest-api-adding-a-label-to-a-node) to your request:

```
[
    {
        "method":"POST",
        "to":"/node",
        "id": 0,
        "body":{"ICD9":"79409","NodeType":"Dx","ID":2}
    },
    {
        "method":"POST",
        "to":"{0}/labels",
        "id": 1,
        "body": "Dx"
    }    
]
```

Since you've already put a label on the node, consider omitting the `NodeType` property - it seems to be redundant.

Comment: This works.  Thanks!  Agree the NodeType is redundant, but left it in for now.  As a relative novice, as others might be, I was unsure about the syntax for the {0}.  So ... here is what worked:  [{"method":"POST","to":"/node","id":8002,"body":{"ICD9":"73394","DIAG_DESC":"STRESS FRACTURE OF THE METATARSALS","NodeType":"Dx"}},{"method":"POST","to":"{8002}/labels","body":["Dx"]},{"method":"POST","to":"/node","id":8003,"body":{"ICD9":"38860","DIAG_DESC":"OTORRHEA NOS","NodeType":"Dx"}},{"method":"POST","to":"{8003}/labels","body":["Dx"]} .... ].